# Compiler doesn't complain when cond doesn't have a else branch and the condition isn't satisfied

Tags: racket

I have the following Racket code:

```
#lang racket

(define (for-each proc items) 
  (cond ((not (null? items)) 
    (proc (car items)) 
    (for-each proc (cdr items))))) 

(for-each (lambda (x) (newline) (display x))
    (list 57 321 88))
```

Because the condition isn't satisfied after 88 is printed, and the Racket's documentation says:

> If none of the question-expressions evaluates to true, cond’s value is the answer-expression of the else clause. If there is no else, cond reports an error.

So the expected result is an error, however I get the correct output:

```
57
321
88
```

Can somebody tell me why? (ps: I'm using DrRacket 6.2)

Comment: In R6RS, it returns 'unspecified'

Comment: You are referring to the wrong docs then. It says: If no cond-clauses are present, the result is #<void>. See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29

Comment: Also see: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html#%28part._cond%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the indentation a little:

```
(define (for-each proc items) 
  (cond
    [(not (null? items)) (proc (car items)) 
                         (for-each proc (cdr items))]))
```

A call `(for-each f (list 1 2 3))`
will call the function and bind `proc` to `f` and `items` to `'(1 2 3)`.

The test `(not (null? items))` is true, since `'(1 2 3)` is non-empty.
The right hand side is therefore evaluated. The right hand side does two things:
1.)  `(proc (car items))` calls `f` with the first element in the list (here 1) and then 2). calls `(for-each proc (cdr items))`. Here `(cdr items)` becomes '(2 3).

Eventually `for-each` will be called with `(for-each f '())`.
At that point `(not (null? items))` will evaluate to `#f` and the `cond` will try the next clause. Since there are no more clauses `cond` will return `void`.

The documentation says:

```
If no cond-clauses are present, the result is #<void>.
```

Note: The `cond` in the teaching languages will return an error. The constructs in the teaching language generally reports errors, where there is a chance of shooting ones own foot.

Comment: Shouldn't the `#void` be printed out?

Comment: @Caesar The value `#void` is special with regards to printing. The printer never prints a single `#void`. If you put it into a list `(list (void))` it will print it. The void value is returned when you want to return nothing - and therefore doesn't want anything printed.

Comment: But look at this, it says the compiler will report an error.[cond in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html#(form._((lib._lang/htdp-advanced..rkt)._cond)))

Comment: Yes - that link goes to the documentation for the teaching language "Advanced". And in the teaching language you will get an "cond: all question results were false" error.

Comment: So Advanced is a variant of Racket? How can I know which Racket I'm using in DrRacket?

Comment: For Advanced etc. you choose the language in the menu of DrRacket. Otherwise you can tell by the first line of a program. `#lang racket` means a full racket program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87902/discussion-between-caesar-and-soegaard).

Comment: Drop by the Racket irc channel then. It's #racket on freenode.

Comment: Seemingly need to be invited.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got that information. To quote the [spec](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html):

> The last test-expr in a cond can be replaced by else. In terms of evaluation, else serves as a synonym for #t, but it clarifies that the last clause is meant to catch all remaining cases. If else is not used, then it is possible that no test-exprs produce a true value; in that case, the result of the cond expression is #void.

Comment: Well I was referring docs in Dash and it says just that. But provided it should produce a `#void`, then output should have a `#void`, but in my output there're just three numbers.

Comment: @Caesar `#void` should be the *return value* of `for-each`, which it is. But since you never print the return value of `for-each`, there's no reason it should appear in the *output*.

Comment: But in Scheme isn't every return value printed automatically even if I don't print it manually? Like I write `(list 1 2)` and run it, the output will be `(1 2)`.

Comment: But look at this, it says the compiler will report an error.[cond in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html#(form._((lib._lang/htdp-advanced..rkt)._cond)))

Comment: @Caesar strange - I'll ask around

Comment: I've joined in. Thank you.